# Inserting a new DITA body element

Tags: xml, xslt, dita

Looking to transform an XML file to a valid DTD topic. To do this I need to insert a body element as shown.

```xml
<topic>
<title>My Title</title>
==><body>
<para>Intro text goes here.</para>
  <section/>
  <section/>
==></body>
</topic>
```

Comment: This is not a simple operation, such as grabbing a single element and wrapping it in a body element. I need to match a group of different elements and wrap them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to add a `body` element as a child of `topic`, add a template that matches `topic` and add the element there.

The only slightly tricky part is that you want the `title` outside of `body`, so you'll have to separate that from the rest of the children.

Here's an XSLT 3.0 example. (I also added an `id` attribute to `topic` and changed `para` to `p` so it would be valid.)

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" doctype-public="-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" doctype-system="topic.dtd"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="topic">
        <topic id="{generate-id()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|title"/>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except title"/>
            </body>
        </topic>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="para">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you can't use XSLT 3.0, here's a 1.0 version (without `xsl:mode` and `except`)...

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" doctype-public="-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" doctype-system="topic.dtd"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="topic">
        <topic id="{generate-id()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|title"/>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::title)]"/>
            </body>
        </topic>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="para">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nzb5iZ

Comment: Thanks for the reply Daniel. That looks easier than I thought. I just have to make sure I do not process the title element.

Comment: I am using xslt 1.0.

Comment: Could you explain the match="topic" step, please?
@*|title means all attributes or title, doesn't it? node()[not(self::title)] is something I cannot understand.

Comment: @mikey - `|` operator in xpath is union ([see here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#node-sets)); not "or". So really you can read that as all attributes and title child elements. The `node()[not(self::title)]` means any node() (element, text, comment, or processing-instruction that isn't a `title`. The `[ ]` after node() is a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#NT-Predicate). The `self::` is an [axis](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#axes). This is all standard xpath so it might help to study up on xpath before XSLT.